# trying to post to php file - server error

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm a newbie here to php and Apache. 
I have an html form:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
<form method="post" action="contact.php"> Email: <input name="email"
 type="text"/><br/> Message:<br/> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40">
  </textarea><br/> <input type="submit"/> </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

I have contact.php located in what I believe is the right place, but when I submit the query, I get "The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/www/contact.php' is not allowed."

When I access contact.php as a url I get strange results (like a repeating File Download message box asking whether I want to Save or Open)

Comment: What is that `<?php` thing doing in your HTML file?

Comment: Sounds like you have a configuration error with Apache! Can you give us some details on your Apache/PHP set-up?

Comment: I loaded everything using EasyPHP, and have just assumed the defaults. I put the html and php files into the www folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using  which is missing in your code.

for your below code will work.

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="contact.php"> Email: <input name="email"
 type="text"/><br/> Message:<br/> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40">
  </textarea><br/> <input type="submit"/> </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK so I got rid of the <?php,   no change

Comment: Nope no other change required. you can use <?php ?> only if you want to compile / render dynamic content / variables / data.

Comment: Error I'm getting when I submit the form:Server Error in '/www' Application.
The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/www/contact.php' is not allowed.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/www/contact.php' is not allowed.

Comment: Is your form page and contact.php are in same root directory under www directory ? If not I would recommend to create one directory and put your files inside.

Comment: Yes they are. The full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www

Comment: So they are in www itself, not a root directory under www. Would that be a problem?

Comment: my index.html file having below code. <code><html>
<body>


<form method="post" action="contact.php"> Email: <input name="email"
 type="text"/><br/> Message:<br/> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40">
  </textarea><br/> <input type="submit"/> </form> 

</body>
</html></code>  and my contact.php is having <code><?php
print_r($_POST);
?></code> and it's working very well.

Comment: i'm  not sure if location would be a problem. can you please write down code of your contact.php file.

Comment: <?php $to = "you@yoursite.com"; 
$subject = "Contact Us"; $email = 
$_REQUEST['email'] ; 
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ; 
$headers = "From: $email"; 
$sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 
if($sent) {print "Your mail was sent successfully"; } 
else {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; } ?>

Comment: I'll try your code instead - maybe there's a glitch in mine, but it is only a copy from a website suggestion and I was going to fine tune it later...

Comment: buddy code is fine. might be problem with your PHP setttings. More over is your local server configured to send an emails?

Comment: OK, as a newbie haven't got a clue about php settings, or local server config! But will persist until it works! Thanks very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing Give Name to Submit Button and second remove

```
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="contact.php"> Email: <input name="email"
 type="text"/><br/> Message:<br/> <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40">
  </textarea><br/> <input type="submit" name="submit" /> </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

and if you can still face an error then try to give full file path in action